# I need help in this proof of this exercise from Fulton's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-schemes

I'm reading [Fulton's algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf).

I'm trying to understand this solution which I found online of the question 4.17 on page 97.

[image]

What I didn't understand is why $V(J_z)$ are exactly those points where $z$ is not defined (see the last line the solution).

Maybe I'm missing something, but I couldn't understand why this is true.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't [delete and repost questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1294537/264) - to get attention, you can make a small edit to bump back to the front page (like I've just done), or you can offer a bounty.

Comment: @ZevChonoles I didn't know it's forbidden. It won't happen again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Write $z = a/b$, with $a, b \in \Gamma_{h}(V)$ forms of the same degree $d$. Note that $\overline{b}z = \overline{a} \in \Gamma_{h}(V)$, and therefore $b \in J_{z}$.

Let $P \in V(J_{z})$. Then $F(P) = 0$, for every polynomial $F \in k[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n+1}]$ such that $\overline{F}z \in \Gamma_{h}(V)$. Since $b \in J_{z}$, we have $b(P) = 0$, and thus $z$ is not defined at $P$. This shows that $V(J_{z})$ is contained in the pole set of $z$.

Conversely, let $P$ be a pole of $z$. Then $a(P) \neq 0$ and $b(P) = 0$. Let $F \in J_{z}$. Then, $\overline{F}z = \overline{G}$, for some $\overline{G} \in \Gamma_{h}(V) = k[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n+1}]/I(V)$. That is, $Fz - G \in I(V)$. Since $I(V)$ is an ideal, $b(Fz - G) = Fa - bG \in I(V)$. Evaluating at $P$, we obtain $0 = F(P)a(P) - b(P)G(P) = F(P)a(P)$, because $b(P) = 0$. Since $a(P) \neq 0$, we conclude that $F(P) = 0$. This shows that the pole set of $z$ is contained in $V(J_{z})$.

Therefore, the pole set of $z$ is exactly $V(J_{z})$; in particular, it is an algebraic subset of $V$, as the solution posted shows.

Comment: In the first line why are you writing $\overline bz=\overline a$, instead of $bz=a$? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Because $\Gamma_{h}(V)$ is the quotient of $k[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n+1}]$ by the ideal $I(V)$, so its elements are classes, denoted by the overline.

Comment: Yes, but $a$ and $b$ are already in $\Gamma_h(V)$, no?

Comment: Yes! And that is not a problem.

Comment: Your proof is really great. It's the only part I couldn't understand. See $a=a'+I(V)$, where $a'$ is a polynomial. You can't say $\overline a$, because $a$ is not a polynomial. Thank you again.

Comment: Both $a$ and $b$ are polynomials defining $z$ as the quotient the quotient $a/b$. I am not saying this is a global representation; it is on an open dense subset of $V$. But it does not matter. If you multiply $z$ by $b$ you get $bz = a$. Then, $\overline{a}z = \overline{b}$.

Comment: I'm thinking about an alternative what do you think? "$z=\overline a/\overline b$, where $\overline a$ and $\overline b$ are the images of the forms of the same degree $a$ and $b$ respectively. Note that $\overline b z=\overline a\in \Gamma_h(V)$ and therefore $b\in J_z$.

Let $P \in V(J_{z})$. Then $F(P) = 0$, for every polynomial $F \in k[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n+1}]$ such that $\overline{F}z \in \Gamma_{h}(V)$. Since $b \in J_{z}$, we have $b(P) = 0$, and then $b(P)\in I(V)$. Therefore $b(P)=\overline 0$ and $z$ isn't defined at $P$. "

Comment: It is Ok! But for me, it is essentially what I wanted to say.

Comment: Using global representations and using your solution I think I can show that $\overline F(P)=\overline 0$, i.e., $F(P)\in I(V)$. I don't know how to get $F(P)=0$. Would you have any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Why is $a(P)\neq0$? So far as the definition is concerned, it only requires that $b(P)=0$

Comment: I think it is because if a(P)=b(P)=0, then a and b has a common factor $(x_i -P)$ and then u can cut it down